# Adding several Azure subscriptions in VMM in System Center 2012 R2

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Since there is a possibility to add an active Azure subscription to your System Center Virtual Machine Manager R2 (I’ve managed that and it works fine) I would like to add several subscriptions in VMM from other users so that I could access those machines and managed them from the console.

Is this possible?

And thank you for your help and opinions.